# How to add actual time taken to finish a task or a story in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am working on **scrum** with **VSTS**(Visual Studio Team Services)

I am able to add estimated effort to backlog items as well as estimated hours to different tasks.

I was wondering if there is a way that allows me to add the actual time taken to finish a specific task. So that I can later have a report or so to see the difference between estimation and actual in order to enhance the team estimation.

Answer (score 5):

Not in the SCRUM Template. That template is all about `remaining time`. I believe the AGILE Template will let you enter `original estimate`, `remaining time` and `time spent`. So perhaps look into that.

Failing that, you could use an add-on. Have a browse of the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/)

This one looks like it might work for you: [TFS Time Tracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Berichthaus.TfsTimetracker)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.I actually like the add-on, but it's paid. Is there any free one you are aware of? Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry

Comment: If you make an make an inherited/custom derivative process in the organization`s==>process dashboard you can add whatever fields you want.

Answer (score 4):

**Completed Work** field is only available for the Agile Template. I believe you can still create a custom template to be able to configure fields in the default template (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/customize-process-field#add-field).

However, VSTS is probably not intended for time tracking. You can try and use time sheet extensions to VSTS.
For example, TFS timesheet (https://www.teamexpand.com/product/tfs-timesheet) allows inputting hours directly from a Work Item tab and generate detailed reports that show how many hours were spent to complete a task with a day-by-day breakdown. It also allows to keep track of actual time vs. estimated time.